# Construction of tree using c4.5 algorithm?

Tags: java, decision-tree

I am implementing decision tree using c4.5 algorithm.I can find the root nodes,their branches and find sub nodes.But to reach the class nodes or leaf nodes ,there are some problems.

For example:

I am using contact-lenses dataset , but I can't find one leaf node.I got this much,

ROOT : [tear-prod-rate]

Branches :-

1.reduced ->[none]

2- normal->[astigmatism]->yes->[spectacle-prescrip]->myope->[hard]

```
                                         ->hypermetrope->[none]

                  ->no->????
```

In the sub node-[astigmatism] , there are two branches yes and no.I only got yes-branch .From that yes -branch I can find the other sub node ->[spectacle-prescrip] and its two branches myope and hypermetrope.

But I don't get astigmatism second branch no and its sub node.

Comment: What about some code? Difficult to answer your problem when it's not even being asked ;)

Comment: Next time one of your questions gets put on hold, it's probably better to edit [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22005167/1468366) than start a new one.